# Singular matrix but it's full rank

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, matlab, multicollinearity, singular-matrix

I'm using matlab to fit a logit GLM to a data (detection problem). I have a Nx5 matrix of independent variables and a binary (i.e 0-1) column vector of responses. When I try to fit the GLM model with `fitglm` I get this warning

```
Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision.
```

which leads to the following error

```
C must be a square, symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix.
```

within `corrcov` function when trying to test the trained model. But if I try `rank(matrix)` being `matrix` my matrix of independent variables I get 5, the number of columns. Also, `rref` gives 5 ones in the diagonal, and the condition number is 73, which I don't see too high. What can I do to solve this problem?

EDIT: There was an error in my matlab command. The problematic command I was issuing was

```
model=fitglm(trainingData,trainingLabels,'link','logit');
```

but, without specifying `'distribution'`, `fitglm` assumes normality, which is not the case dealing with binary responses. So I issued

```
reglog=fitglm(trainingData,trainingLabels,'distribution','binomial','link','logit');
```

and then everything worked fine.

(Not sure if I must add my solution here or as an aswer and mark as solved)

Comment: Does your matrix of IVs include a column of 1s (a global intercept) or regressors that add up to such a column?

Comment: @RubenvanBergen no, it doesn't include a column of ones. Could you explain what do you mean "regressors that add up to such a column"? Besides, adding the column of ones yields to a new warning: Regression design matrix is rank deficient to within machine precision.

Comment: Okay, I asked because fitglm already adds an intercept automatically, so if you include one as well then you end up with two intercepts which, obviously, are collinear, and that could have explained the warning. What I meant by "regressors that add up to such a column" is a set of regressors that you can combine to get a global intercept. E.g. if you had several groups or conditions in your data and you modeled individual intercepts for each, then together those would be collinear with a global intercept term, and so you'd have to leave one out to keep the matrix full-rank.

Comment: No. My columns are the standardized outputs of several sensors and there's a column that's a ratio between two of those columns. In both cases, `rank(matrix)`=5